# Namespace Definition Outside of Source

Tags: c++, namespaces

I want to put some `myClass` objects in namespaces and use them in my main function. The following strategy works, but the namespace definitions take up a lot of lines, and the user really doesn't need to see them.

How can I move the namespaces/variable initializations into an included file?

```
// Main.C:
namespace Ns1{
    myClass* mycA = new myClass(constant1A);
    myClass* mycB = new myClass(constant1B);
    /// ... lots more vars
}

namespace Ns2{
    myClass* mycA = new myClass(constant2A);
    myClass* mycB = new myClass(constant2B);
    /// ... all/many of the same vars as in ns1
}

void main(){
  int param = 0; // param determined in main()
  Ns1::mycA->setOtherVars(param);
  Ns2::mycB->accessSomething();
  // clean up!?
}
```

I have researched and tried a lot of possible solutions, but everything seems to have pitfalls. For example:

- these objects aren't `consts`; if they were I think that would solve some problems.
- `static` initializers are bad, especially for user-defined types.
- Globals are bad, so I want to avoid that.
- I tried *declaring* the variables inside of the namespaces (in a header file) and calling `initializeNs1Vars()` and `vector<myC*> getNs1Vars()`. I don't remember what went wrong with that one. Maybe this is my most promising route?
- Messing with `extern` just seemed to add a lot more code.
- And what about clean up!?

---

EDIT: OK, variables in namespaces are veiled globals. Is there another way to define lots of variables in a more compact way?

```
void main(){
  myClass* mycA_1 = new myClass(constant1A);
  myClass* mycB_1 = new myClass(constant1B);
  //... lots more objects
  myClass* mycA_2 = new myClass(constant2A);
  myClass* mycB_2 = new myClass(constant2B);
  //... lots more objects

  // as before
}
```

Comment: "Globals are bad, so I want to avoid that." what else do you have there? You have a bunch of globals and dont know where to put them, imho the best answer is: dont make them globals ;)

Comment: Variables inside a namespace are basically the same as global variables. You can *declare* them in a header file and then use separate source files for their *definitions*. However, "basically the same as global varibles" should cause warning-bells to ring, as global variables are kind of bad.

Comment: It's hard to say which architecture would suit your project the best just looking at this example. Without being rude, I would like to ask why you need to create these many objects in a hard-coded way? Perhaps you could loop over all the constants you need to generate a myClass for and store them in a std::vector or a std::map for later use?

Additionally, it's always a good idea to avoid using 'new' explicitly in order to simplify the memory management. I would advice just using a stack variable, or unique_ptr<myClass> if you really need to store it on the heap.